# Promoting release from "Internal test" track to production

Tags: android, google-play-console, beta-distribution

There is a possibility to promote Alpha/Beta releases to production with a single click of a button, but for some reason "Internal test" track doesn't have "Release to production" button and only "Release to alpha/beta".

I cannot find any documentation on the topic and wonder if it is something that is prevented on purpose or I'm simply missing something.

Right now the workaround is to promote release to Alpha first and only then from Alpha to production. But it doesn't make much sense, because these alpha/beta stages are not currently used for any kind of pre-release testing.

Alternatively, I can every time create a separate release for production and just select the same APK, but it also doesn't make sense when some release notes and other metadata already specified in "Internal test" release and all this info should be copied manually.

Comment: Curious to know if this is the first time the app is being released? Maybe there are still somethings incomplete that is preventing it from being release to production like assets, graphics, content rating, pricing distribution etc?

Comment: No, it has already been released to production. I'm just trying now to handle DevOps properly and make good use of this "Internal test" track. I'll add more details to the question on how it is handled now.

Comment: I agree, it would make sense to be able to promote an app straight from an internal test to production if you aren't using alpha or beta testing. However, imagine you are in charge of the "Google" app, which likely has a long testing process, and the developers have mistakenly just added some code that breaks the app into an internal test. But rather than rolling back the update, you hit the big "Promote to Production" button, and suddenly billions of users can't use Google. Not having that button is to protect these major app developers against that, but is rather annoying for the rest of us.

Comment: @Sub6Resources Nah, I don't think it is possible to promote something accidentally, cause promotion requires at least 3 button clicks (Promote -> Review -> Start roll-out). But yeah, that was my thought as well, Google once again enforces some behaviour without the ability to customize the workflow. At least it seems like it, I still might be wrong about something.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As of this time, Google does allow you to promote an "Internal testing" release to Production.

Under Release on the left, then under Internal testing in the left, click on Internal Testing and then, on the right/main pane click on Promote Release and then choose Closed testing, Open testing or Production.

Comment: Note that you have to manually release your first production release. Otherwise the production track is 'inactive' and will not be available in the 'promote' drop-down.

Comment: @Marty
I try promote Closed testing to Production, I'm getting error like this "An active app bundle was uploaded before you chose your app signing key.".
Do I really need to manually release first time?

Answer (score 11):

In the new Google Play Console (October 2020) you will find it on the right-hand-side menu in:

`Release > Testing > Closed/Open Testing > Manage Track > Promote Release > Production`

[image]

Answer (score 6):

`App releases > Production track` click `Edit Releases`
click `From Library` and choose the APK (by version number) that is in `Internal test`

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I was mot able to promote my app from internal test to production.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I was unable to promote to Production because there was a pending untitled release under production.  I found the release under Production>Releases and clicked "Discard release".  Then I was able to promote my Internal testing bundle to production.